# Apache Drill Web Interface

Tags: apache-drill

I have authentication turned on with Apache Drill 1.10 and can use sqlline and jdbc fine with my configured users. However when I try logging into the web console I can log in but then when I click on the query button I am always redirected to the login page again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In /conf/drill-override.conf, enable https by adding "drill.exec.http.ssl_enabled: true"
Then connect with https:\:8047
This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I meant connect to https:\\<drillbit ip>:8047

Comment: Also see, https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-web-console-and-rest-api-security/#https-support